AttributeError: type object 'TypeInformation' has no attribute 'of' in DeserializationSchema python class
I try to make some pyflink codes to deserialize the csv type data from Kafka consumer. First I made DeserializationSchema class like below,
from pyflink.common import DeserializationSchema, Types, TypeInformation
 
class CustomCsvDeserializationSchema(DeserializationSchema):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    def deserialize(self, value):
        str_list = value.split(',')
        if str_list[0] != 'date' and str_list[1] != None and str_list[1] != 'null':
            return str_list
 
    def is_end_of_stream(self, next_element):
        return False
 
    def get_produced_type(self):
        type_info = Types.ROW([Types.STRING(), Types.FLOAT(), Types.STRING()\
            , Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()])
        
        return TypeInformation.of(type_info)   # This line throws the exception.

And I invoke the above deserialization class on the below python function.
def getDS(self, kafka_topic):
    kafka_brokerlist = self._config['KAFKA_CONFIG']['kafka.brokerlist']
        
    source = KafkaSource.builder() \
        .set_bootstrap_servers(kafka_brokerlist) \
        .set_topics(kafka_topic) \
        .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()) \
        .set_value_only_deserializer(CustomCsvDeserializationSchema()) \
        .build()
 
    ds = self._env.from_source(source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "Kafka Source", CustomCsvDeserializationSchema().get_produced_type())
        
    return ds

The error message is AttributeError: type object 'TypeInformation' has no attribute 'of'.
My reference site is this link. And as you see, the overrided getProducedType() function returns TypeInformation.of value in java codes. But in these python codes, TypeInformation class has no attribute 'of'. Kindly inform me how to fix these errors.
